# Is there a way to get a complete expression with the ReplyKeyboard in python-telepot for telegram bot?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telepot

I'm doing a telegram bot with python-telepot and I want to create a keyboard with ReplyKeyboardMarkup, this keyboard has the function of entering a mathematical expression that I want to derive (apply the function of derivatives) I show you the keyboard code:

```py
if data == 'resol_der':
        bot.answerCallbackQuery(query_id, text='Use the keyboard to insert')
        markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
        keyboard=[
            [KeyboardButton(text='0'),KeyboardButton(text='1'),KeyboardButton(text='2'),KeyboardButton(text='3'),KeyboardButton(text='4'),
            KeyboardButton(text='5'),KeyboardButton(text='6'),KeyboardButton(text='7'),KeyboardButton(text='8'),KeyboardButton(text='9')],
            [KeyboardButton(text='+'),KeyboardButton(text='-'),KeyboardButton(text='*'),KeyboardButton(text='/'),KeyboardButton(text='='),
            KeyboardButton(text='('),KeyboardButton(text=')'),KeyboardButton(text=','),KeyboardButton(text='x**'),KeyboardButton(text='√')],
            [KeyboardButton(text='send'),KeyboardButton(text='/start')],
            ]
            )           
        bot.sendChatAction(from_id, 'typing')
        bot.sendMessage(from_id, 'OK! Give me the expression', reply_markup=markup)
```

look like this
[Make the ReplyKeyboardMarkup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNuMx.png)

It works well, but the complication I want to solve is that I need the keyboard to wait for a complete expression, because when I click on each button of the created keyboard, the character goes to the chat ... and I need to load an entire expression in string

How can I do so that the keyboard allows the one who interacts with the bot to use the buttons and structure a complete expression that is sent to the chat so that it can be processed by another function?

Thank you in advance for any guidance you may have to comment ...

Comment: Why can't you use regular keyboard?

Comment: The idea is to provide a keyboard similar to a scientific calculator that allows the bot user to enter a mathematical expression to which to apply the function of the derivative.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's called a "keyboard", these buttons are simply templates for messages.

If you really wish to create a math keyboard, use [inline keyboard](https://core.telegram.org/bots#inline-keyboards-and-on-the-fly-updating) with on-the-fly message editing. You'll have to get callback buttons' presses and update your bot's message accordingly. I'm not sure it's worth doing, but it's all up to you.